# MVCP100D.dll missing when running exe file generated by C++ code in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-7, visual-studio-2015, ampl

I am trying to integrate [AMPL](http://ampl.com/) with C/C++ using [AMPL-API](http://ampl.com/products/api/). I created a Makefile project in Eclipse which uses MinGW CC to compile the code.

> Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ampl/ampl.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ampl::AMPL ampl;

    // Read the model and data files.
    std::string modelDirectory = "models";
    ampl.read(modelDirectory + "/diet/diet.mod");
    ampl.readData(modelDirectory + "/diet/diet.dat");

    // Solve
    ampl.solve();

    // Get objective entity by AMPL name
    ampl::Objective totalcost = ampl.getObjective("total_cost");
    // Print it
    std::cout << "Objective is: " << totalcost.value() << std::endl;
}
```

> Following is my Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0
INCLUDES = -I "C:\\Local\\AMPL\\amplide.mswin32\\amplide.mswin32\\amplapi\\include"
OBJS = AMPL.o
LIBS =  -lampl1.2.2 
TARGET = AMPL.exe
$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -L "./" -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
AMPL.o: AMPL.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c AMPL.cpp
all:    $(TARGET)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

> Contents of my project directory are:

- .settings/
- models/

  - diet/

    - diet.dat
    - diet.mod
- .cproject
- .project
- AMPL.cpp
- AMPL.exe
- AMPL.o
- ampl1.2.2.lib
- Makefile

I am having a 32-bit Windows 7 machine which have both Eclipse Mars 2.0 and Visual Studio 2015 installed on it. Whenever I run exe file, it says MVCP100D.dll is missing. I looked on web and found that this error generally comes when Visual C++ Redistributable are missing. But my system has redistributable installed on it. Please help me with this.

**Update:** I tried to execute same code over Visual Studio 2015 and there also it is able to compile, however, I am unable to run *.exe file. It also says MVCP100D.dll is missing. I am not sure why this error is coming, please help!!

**Update:** Downloading the updated version works in Visual Studio 2015 but facing a separate problem specified in other post: [Undefined reference to (error) in C++ Eclipse but working in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37581483/1434693)

Comment: MVCP100D.dll is a debug dll (note the D on the end of the name) and has nothing to do with redistributables.  Are you having this problem on your development computer or another one?  More details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e128dff6-cef5-4a81-b6de-fcbcaa7a23bb/msvcp100ddll-is-missing?forum=Vsexpressvc

Comment: Thanks Richard for a prompt response! This is happening on my development computer only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the beta version of the [AMPL](http://ampl.com/) C++ API. As a quick fix, the updated distribution available for download from http://ampl.com/products/api includes these DLLs. A permanent fix will be available in the next corrective release.

Comment: Sure. Don't forget to vote/accept if it answers your question ;-)

Comment: I don't have much reputation to upvote or accept the answer. But I will do mention +1 :) 

I am facing another issue now. My code works on VS2015 now but gives error in Eclipse. Can I post it here or start a new thread?

Comment: I suggest opening a separate question.